# How do I combine ActiveRecord results from multiple has_many :through queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Basically, I have an app with a tagging system and when someone searches for tag 'badger', I want it to return records tagged "badger", "Badger" and "Badgers".
With a single tag I can do this to get the records:

```
@notes = Tag.find_by_name(params[:tag_name]).notes.order("created_at DESC")
```

and it works fine. However if I get multiple tags (this is just for upper and lower case - I haven't figured out the 's' bit either yet):

```
Tag.find(:all, :conditions => [ "lower(name) = ?", 'badger'])
```

I can't use .notes.order("created_at DESC") because there are multiple results. 
So, the question is.... 1) Am I going about this the right way?  2) If so, how do I get all my records back in order?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?  What DB are you using?

Comment: Rails 3.2 / sqlite3. My comment on @gazler's answer ended up doing the trick for anyone else looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One implementation would be to do:

```
@notes = []
Tag.find(:all, :conditions => [ "lower(name) = ?", 'badger']).each do |tag|
  @notes << tag.notes
end
@notes.sort_by {|note| note.created_at}
```

However you should be aware that this is what is known as an N + 1 query, in that it makes one query in the outer section, and then one query per result.  This can be optimized by changing the first query to be:

```
Tag.find(:all, :conditions => [ "lower(name) = ?", 'badger'], :includes => :notes).each do |tag|
```

If you are using Rails 3 or above, it can be re-written slightly:

```
Tag.where("lower(name) = ?", "badger").includes(:notes) do |tag|
```

Comment: Also to return plurals you can either just change the `"lower(name) = ?",'badger'` to `" lower(name) LIKE ?", "#{param[:tag_name]}%"`

Comment: True, but both `lower` and `like` are very slow. The combination could be terrible for large sets of tags.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! Didn't quite work but it lead me to something that did: `@notes = Note.joins(:tags).where("lower(name) = ?", params[:tag_name].downcase)`. That gave me a hash in @notes I could pass to the view. Don't fully understand why the `.includes(:notes)` thing didn't work, but got there in the end eh. Thanks very very much anyway! Couldn't have done it without this.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

First, get an array of all possible tag names, plural, singular, lower, and upper

```
tag_name = params[:tag_name].to_s.downcase
possible_tag_names = [tag_name, tag_name.pluralize, tag_name.singularize].uniq
# It's probably faster to search for both lower and capitalized tags than to use the db's `lower` function
possible_tag_names += possible_tag_names.map(&:capitalize)
```

Are you using a tagging library? I know that some provide a method for querying multiple tags. If you aren't using one of those, you'll need to do some manual SQL joins in your query (assuming you're using a relational db like MySQL, Postgres or SQLite). I'd be happy to assist with that, but I don't know your schema.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The one from @gazler ended up getting me there but thanks for the warning about lower and LIKE. Reckon I can definitely do it without the latter one.